# How can I plot Trajectory of 3d parametric plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, parametric-functions

x1 and y1 are constants.

I have plotted ParametricPlot3D.

```
x1= 0.1;
y1= 0.2;
eps = 0.1;
X=ParametricPlot3D[{
(1-ε)*x1+ε*x2,
(1-ε)*y1 + ε*y2,
(1-ε)*x1*y1+ε*x2*y2
}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}]
```

I want to plot trajectory of X when ε is continuously changing 0 to 0.5 as 3D plot.
I mean I want to plot 3D space which X can be satisfied when ε is continuously changing 0 to 0.5.

How can I do that?

The below image is producted by adding X each ε. I think we can find better way.

[image: plot]

Comment: I think eps should be ε. Anyway, you could try this: `x1 = 0.1;
y1 = 0.2;
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot3D[{(1 - ε)*x1 + ε*
     x2, (1 - ε)*y1 + ε*
     y2, (1 - ε)*x1*y1 + ε*x2*y2}, {x2, 0,
    1}, {y2, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, .6}, {0, .6}, {0, .6}}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1]
 , {ε, 0, 0.5}]`

Answer (score 2):

To plot the volume try `ParametricRegion` as follows:

First do linear interpolation of your expression

```
f0 = {(1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*x1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*x2, (1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*y1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*y2, (1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*x1*y1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*x2*y2} /. \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 0
f1 = {(1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*x1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*x2, (1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*y1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*y2, (1 - \[CurlyEpsilon])*x1*y1 + \[CurlyEpsilon]*x2*y2} /. \[CurlyEpsilon] -> 1/2
ip = Function[{x2, y2, u}, Evaluate[ (1/2 - u)/(1/2) f0 + u/(1/2) f1]]
```

second define and plot a parametric region

```
reg = ParametricRegion[ip[x2, y2, u], {{u, 0, 1/2}, {x2, 0, 1}, {y2, 0, 1}} ]
Show[Region[reg], MaxRecursion -> 4, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Perhaps that's the volume you are looking for.
How to refine the plot I unfortunately don't know.